# create scatter plot with multiple Y axis values for each x axis value

Tags: r, excel, plot

I have excel data that looks like this -

```
[![PROBE_DESIGN_ID  POSITION    A1801_Med   A1802_Med   A1803_Med   A1804_Med   A1805_Med
621931_0250_0258    1   47.75   51.14   95.05   49.37   52.87
621931_0251_0031    5   41.96   42.97   52.65   42.34   43.13
621931_0233_0683    9   42.57   51.98   64.63   53.13   52.75
621931_0007_0553    13  57.65   50.65   71.4    53.47   54.03
621931_0011_0143    17  304.7   540.63  648.03  181.46  209.57
621931_0100_0644    21  424.19  163.48  1790.23 241.24  209.18
621931_0353_0701    25  330.74  35023.05    4004.88 1178.53 439.69][1]][1]
```

And I need to create a plot with all values from column 3-7 corresponding to each "Position" stack over Y axis. For example the plot here has values for just position 1 and 5. I need to create a plot with all 2nd column positions on X axis. Can it be done easily in excel or should I look into R? The actual file has around 90 position values in it. 
[image]
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy in Excel. Just select the `position` column as well as the additional columns, and click on Insert > Scatterplot

[image: excel]

Depending on your value range, you may want to enable logarithmic axes on the y axis:

[image]

Example based on Excel for Mac Office 365, 2016

Comment: Thanks a lot Serban! This is so easy, and I kept trying inconclusive methods thinking that it will be too complicated! Thanks again for such easy and fast reply. converting axis to log did help in viewing data properly.